# What's a good strategy for FNAF 3?

Tags: five-nights-at-freddys-3

I got FNAF 3 recently and I've been having a lot of trouble with Night 3. I always seem to get multiple errors and while I'm rebooting the systems Springtrap either completely disappears or comes and kills me.

When and Where should I be using my audio lures? What should I do about the Shadow Animitronics? What do I do if Springtrap get's into the hallway outside my office?

Comment: Questions about game play strategies are allowed on Arqade. While some opinion is going to show up in the answers it still is a valid question.

Comment: Which hallway outside of your office? Directly forward, or to the left hand side?

Comment: @Corsaka Either, really what should I do when Springtrap is just a few seconds away.

Comment: When he's on the left-hand side, all you can do is wait and hope the ventilation doesn't go out; once there he'll jumpscare you as soon as you put up a camera.
If he's directly outside in the hallway, you can attempt to lure him away, but that's about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Dealing with Springtrap:**

Most of the time you'll want to keep Springtrap in Room 09 or 10. He'll start in a room between 5 and 10, so you may need 2 audio lures; you should have at least two per reboot.

If you lose him, look in the cameras nearest to where you last saw him. If you hear bumping in the vents, it means he's in one; seal it very quickly, as all of them lead directly to the office (and thus lose you the game). If you find Springtrap, you should be able to lead him back to the room you want him in.

This game is however decently RNG based - you have a chance to have all of your audio lures fail to attract Springtrap, so you will likely need multiple attempts.

---

**Countering phantom animatronics:**

- Phantom Chica is the simplest, appearing only on CAM 07. You simply need to swap cameras when she's on the screen; her jumpscare will reset the ventilation systems.
- Phantom BB is the next easiest to deal with. He'll appear most commonly on either CAM 07, 09, or 10, (but can appear anywhere) covering the camera completely. You simply need to either lower the camera or swap cameras to clear him. Not clearing him in time will force you to reset your ventilation system.
- Phantom Mangle is similar - she'll appear on CAM 04, and you need to swap camera to clear her. However, if you don't clear her in time, you'll have to reset your audio and ventilation systems, and Springtrap is more likely to be attracted to your office.
- Phantom Foxy is slightly harder, as he will appear behind the screen when the cameras are up. Whenever you go to the left to reset your systems, first go completely left and then back to the right to see if Foxy is there. If he is, then open and close the camera so he leaves. Not clearing Foxy will cause your ventilation and one of camera/audio systems to fail.
- Phantom Freddy requires you to let him stumble fully across the hallway, from right to left. This is generally done by keeping the camera or monitor up - he'll disable your ventilation systems if triggered.
- Phantom Marionette (Phantom Puppet) cannot be avoided; rarely, when looking at CAM 08, The Puppet will be seen standing there. The cameras will be lowered almost immediately, and for 15-17 seconds, The Phantom Puppet will move left to right, tracking the player with its eyes and allowing other animatronics such as Phantom Freddy and Phantom Foxy to attack. You will be unable to open the monitor or cameras while they are active.

  ---

  **Extra tips:**

  - Try to reboot the audio right after use, to prevent it from crashing at the wrong time. This is especially effective on nights 5 and 6.
  - Try to seal the vent nearest to Springtrap constantly.
  - If 2 things go offline at once, reboot all, it's faster.

Answer (score -2):

I like to just go for it and see what happens, but I'm pretty sure a good technique is to check the cams, lure springy to CAM8 
Then fix the video, check cams again, then continue that strategy till 4:00 AM, then, till 6 you just wing it!!

Comment: But what about the shadow animitronics and the other errors? And why does the strategy change from 4am to 6am? Why is Cam 8 the best choice?

Comment: Well, I am not really saying this is the best strat, but it works for me. If it doesn't work for you then I can't help, maybe it works differently on PC. It sort of depends on your platform. I personally use mobile, but I'm afraid I can't really awnser those questions. Sorry if I didn't help! 